# error while parsing value using Double.parseDouble

Tags: java

I have a code :

variables : Double meter, km ;

it has to convert Km to meters and pass the value to the text fiels in this case "tfm"

```
meter=km*1000;

Double.parseDouble(tfm.setText(meter));
```

However it show error which says: 
incompatible types : double cannot be converted to string

Does anybody knows how to fix it ?

Thank you in Advance

Comment: Please read this first: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `getText` instead of `setText`... and `setText(doubleVariable + "");`

Comment: Change meter to text before you try to put it in the text field.

tfm.setText(Double.toString(meter));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set any value to label :

```
label.setText(YourValue);
```

so , in your case use this line:

```
tfm.setText(meter+"");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
meter = km * 1000;
```

is correct. However, in your line of

```
Double.parseDouble(tfm.setText(meter));
```

You have several problems:

`setText` expects `String` and is `void`, therefore you cannot use its value, as seen [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TextField.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29). You try to use this `void` as a parameter at `parseDouble`, which expects `String`, seen [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29). You should have something like:

```
tfm.setText(meter + "");
```

instead.